# Fail Gitlab commit when not passing Sonarqube Quality Gates

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

For integrating Sonarqube with my Gitlab CI, I want a commit to fail when it doesn't pass the Quality Gate in Sonarqube. I have set up my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to analyze every commit with Sonarqube, but the commit is succesfull regardless of the outcome. As long as the scan is completed succesfully, the commit is passed. How can I make sure my commit fails when it doesn't pass the Quality Gate in Sonarqube?

I have set everything up based on this post: [SonarQube autorun with gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323223/sonarqube-autorun-with-gitlab)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the parameter sonar.qualitygate.wait=true